# How to call an object of class in global function in c++?

Tags: c++, object

I have a global function `void start_menu()` which I'm using as an interface.

```
void start_menu()
{
    int x;

    cout << " ------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " WELCOME TO LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "                    1. ABOUT Books    " << endl;
    cout << "                    2. ABOUT Members    " << endl;
    cout << "            CHOOSE:";
    cin >> x;

    Books MyBooks; //object of books class

    do
    {
        if (x==1)
        {
            system("cls");

            MyBooks.INTR_Books(); //calling function of Books Class      
         }
     };
}
```

Then, I have `class Books{}` which I want to be called in global function `void start_menu()` but when I make an object of `Books` class, which is defined as `Books MyBooks;`, the above code gave me this error:

> error: 'Books' was not declared in this scope.

This is `Books` class after the global function `void start_menu()`:

```
class Books
{
public:
    string BookName; //name of the Book
    string Auth;   //Author of the book
    string Trans;   // translator of the book
    string myArray[20];
    int BookCode; // code of the book
    int BookNum;  // number of copies exist

    void INTR_Books(); //show interface related to books
    void ADD_BOOK();
    void DELETE_BOOK();
    void SEARCH();  
    void SHOW_ALL(); 
    void BR_BOOK(); 
};
```

Comment: Is `Books` declared before or after the function?

Comment: @NathanOliver, it will also need definition.

Comment: @Incomputable True, but that can come latter or from another file.

Comment: @NathanOliver after the function

Comment: @moh89, pull it above the function.

Comment: Oversimplification: The C++ compiler does a single pass, if something is not declared before you use it the compiler does not know what it is and errors.

Comment: @NathanOliver what u said i did and it works! but when i call 'start_menu()' elsewhere gaves me same error!

Comment: And also having global functions is not really OOPish

Comment: @Chaosit corrected!

Comment: @NathanOliver `Books` must be defined *before* `start_menu`. `Books::INTR_Books` on the other hand can be defined elsewhere.

Comment: @user2079303 Yep, you're right.  The class must be defined, the member function need not be defined.  Got that mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on comments ,i had undrestood which `Books`class should be called after `void start_menu()` global function.